# Django Rest Framwork Writable Nested serialization

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have used [Writable Nested Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#writable-nested-serialization) in my `serializer` and used `create` method like this:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    billing = BillingSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        billing_data = validated_data.pop('billing')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Billing.objects.create(**billing_data)
        return order
```

I can create nested data. but when I get a view it displays like this:

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "billing": {},
        "quantity": 3,
        "delivery_date": "2017-01-27T15:44:40Z",
        "base_rate": "90.00",
        "is_delivered": false,
        "created_at": "2017-01-26T07:26:53.194450Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-01-26T07:26:53.194495Z",
        "user_id": 1
    }
```

Empty dict for billing. My models are as follows:

```
class Billing(models.Model):
    paid_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_billed = models.DecimalField(default=90.00, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at',)
        verbose_name = 'Billing'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Billings'

class Order(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='orders', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(10)])
    delivery_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=1))
    base_rate = models.DecimalField(default=90.00, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    is_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    billing = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at',)
        verbose_name = 'Order'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Orders'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

Here is my oderView:

```
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, permissions.IsAdminUser,)
```

How can I get my expected data?

Comment: You have `billing` field as TextField in model definition, redefine it with ForeignKey. This should work

Comment: billing = models.ForeignKey('Billing') ?

Comment: IntegrityError at /api/orders/
(1048, "Column 'billing_id' cannot be null")

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved using billing as Foreignkey:
in `order` model:

```
billing = models.ForeignKey(Billing, related_name='orders', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

As it was showing:

> IntegrityError at /api/orders/ (1048, "Column 'billing_id' cannot be
>   null")

It was solved my changing create method in `OrderSerializer`:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    billing_data = validated_data.pop('billing')
    billing = Billing.objects.create(**billing_data)
    billing.save()
    order = Order.objects.create(billing_id=billing.id, **validated_data)
    return order
```